# ReactJS Route after authentication via firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router-dom

I have firebase auth in my reactjs app and want to redirect to /home if user logged in (pass correct email and password) and then show me another component.
I managed to push to /home after login. But it also works if I add /home to url without (correct) user log in data.
Can someone help me to route only if user data correct? It's my first use of react router.

So my Login.js

```
import React from "react";
import {auth} from "../firebase";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      isAuthenticated: false,
    };

    this.onChangeHandler = this.onChangeHandler.bind(this);
    this.onSubmitHandler = this.onSubmitHandler.bind(this);
}

  onChangeHandler(e) {
    if (e.target.name === "email") {
      this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
    }

    if (e.target.name === "password") {
      this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
    }
  }

  onSubmitHandler() {
    let email = this.state.email;
    let password = this.state.password;

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);


      auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
        if (user) {
          this.setState({isAuthenticated: true});
          console.log("USER " + user.email);
        } 
      });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div name="login-form">
        <header>
          <h1>Headline</h1>
          <h2>Login</h2>
        </header>
          <input
            placeholder="email"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
            value={this.state.email}
          ></input>
          <input
            placeholder="password"
            type="password"
            name="password"
            onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
            value={this.state.password}
            required={true}
          ></input>
          
          <div>
            {this.state.isAuthenticated ? <Router> <Redirect to='/home'/></Router> : null}
            <button onClick={() => {this.onSubmitHandler()}}>Login</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import Login from './components/Login';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <Login/>
        </Route>
        <Route exact path="/home">
          <h1>Test</h1>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

There's also a firebase.js which contains the initialization and `export const auth = firebase.auth();`

I have read something about private routes but I'm not sure how to use it as I'm still a beginner in ReactJS.

Comment: Look this tutorial: https://blog.bitsrc.io/authen-route-in-react-firebase-5d56dcb1fa37